# COUNTIFS with floating criteria matching the next value in a column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have the following example data with four **columns** **Class**, **ID**, **Type** and **Code**:

```
Class   ID  Type    Code
Class1  ID1         Code1
Class1  ID1 Type1   
Class1  ID1 Type2   
Class1  ID1     
Class1  ID1         Code1
Class1  ID1     
Class1  ID1 Type1   
Class1  ID1         Code1
Class1  ID1 Type2   
Class1  ID1     
Class1  ID1         Code1
Class1  ID1     
Class1  ID1 Type2   
Class1  ID1 Type1   
Class1  ID1         Code1
Class1  ID1 Type2   
Class1  ID1 Type2   
Class1  ID1 Type2
```

I have the following formula:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A;"Class1";$B:$B;"ID1";$D:$D;"code1")
```

**BUT** I want to achieve a `countifs` formula with an additional condition:
*count only those `code1`s that have `type1` as the next occurence in column **TYPE***

So I will have:
by maintaining the above conditions in the formula and adding the additional condition:
the `count` of **code1** with **type1** as the next occurrence will be **2**. And similarly, the `count` of **code1** with **type2** as the next occurrence in `TYPE column` will be **3**.

**Edit:**
Actually I know how to find my nth match using:

```
SMALL(IF($C$1:$C$51="type1";ROW($C$1:$C$51);"");1)
```

but I don't know how to merge these two formulas.

Acually, I can already locate my `code1` and then in relation to its cell reference locate my `type1` in the previous column **one row** below, but it is not always one row below, sometimes it is two or three or more.

```
=OFFSET(INDEX($D:$D;MATCH(1;(D:D="code1")*(A:A="class1");0);1);1;-1;1;1)
```

I feel that it has something to do with `sumproduct` and `offset` or `index/match`, but I cannot find my way through it.

**P.S. ** I also tried the following, but still no result:

```
=MMULT(($A:$A="Class1")*($B:$B="ID1")*($D:$D="code1");N(OFFSET(INDEX($D:$D;MATCH(1;(D:D="code1")*(A:A="class1");0);1);1;-1;1;1)="type1"))
```

### UPDATE

Since it seems a bit of problem achieving this, I am adding this update to see how we can achieve this using a UDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overly complex array formulas chew calculation resources up quickly and looking for the first non-blank entry in an offsetting range comes into this category. Sometimes it is simply easier to introduce a *helper column* with a portion of the information necessary to arrive at an expedient result.

In an unused column to the right use this standard formula in row 2.

```
=IF(LEN($D2), INDEX($C2:$C$999, MATCH("*", $C2:$C$999, 0)), "")
```

Edit the *999* ending row if you need more rows. It can be left alone if you have less. As a standard formula this is entered normally. Fill down as necessary to catch all of the returns.

[image: Helper Columns for COUNT]

The `MATCH("*", $C2:$C$999, 0)` could also be `MATCH("Type*", $C2:$C$999, 0)` is you need more specific lookups.

Now you can use a conventional (and efficient) [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) to achieve your results.

**Addendum:** UDF alternative

[image: UDF for condition floating range COUNT]

The code for the UDF is:

```
Function udf_CountIf_Next_Item(rR1 As Range, sS1 As String, _
    rR2 As Range, sS2 As String, rR3 As Range, sS3 As String, _
    rR4 As Range, sS4 As String, Optional sS5 As String = "")

    Dim rw As Long, rws As Long, n As Long
    With Intersect(rR1.Parent.UsedRange, rR1)
        rws = .Rows.Count
    End With
    For rw = 1 To rws
        If LCase(rR1(rw).Value2) = LCase(sS1) Then
            If LCase(rR2(rw).Value2) = LCase(sS2) Then
                If LCase(rR3(rw).Value2) = LCase(sS3) Then
                    If Not IsError(Application.Match(sS5 & Chr(42), rR4(rw).Resize(999, 1), 0)) Then
                        If LCase(Application.Index(rR4(rw).Resize(999, 1), _
                          Application.Match(sS5 & Chr(42), rR4(rw).Resize(999, 1), 0))) = LCase(sS4) Then
                            n = n + 1
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next rw

    udf_CountIf_Next_Item = n

End Function
```

> syntax:
>  
> udf_CountIf_Next_Item(*<1<sup>st</sup> column>, <1<sup>st</sup> criteria>, <2<sup>nd</sup> column>, <2<sup>nd</sup> criteria>, <3<sup>rd</sup> column>, <3<sup>rd</sup> criteria>,  <special floating column>, <4<sup>th</sup> criteria>, [optional]<partial floating criteria>*)

The formula in J7 of the above sample image is:

```
=udf_CountIf_Next_Item($A:$A, $F7,$B:$B, $G7,$D:$D, $I7,$C:$C, $H7, "Type")
```

Full column references shouldn't be a problem as the UDF truncates them to the boundaries of the worksheet's UsedRange property. Partial column references like A2:A99 can still be used.

Comment: thank you so much. This is a great idea to do this using a helper column. But as you might have guessed from my previous question, I am dealing with a very complex data set, and I am not allowed to have helper columns. Do you know any other way to achieve this using a formula? if not, I think I need to add vba to the tags so that we could find a solution using a vba code, but I am trying to avoid this because of many reasons.

Comment: It is marginally doable with an array formula but *very* doable with a VBA User Defined Function (aka UDF). The reason I chose the helper column approach is that the array formula's cal;culation laod would have been prohibitive for anything more than 1K rows.

Comment: could you please help me the array formula that you are talking about? cal load is not a problem at all.

Comment: @Mpondomise - I've given it a couple of attempts ad it always seems to be just one more level of array processing that I cannot wrap into it.

Comment: I appreciate your attempts to answer this question using formula. If you think it is not possible to do it using a formula, then how can we do it using a vba code? a UDF that we can use in the countifs formula or instead of it? i edited the tags.

Comment: @Mpondomise - see addendum above

Comment: @Mpondomise - BTW, due to the nested If statements, that function will run faster if the rarest matches are put first. If A:A matches 50% of the time and B:B matches 10% of the time, use B:B as the first column and  criteria. It will kick out to the next row without processing any further on no match so the rarest set of column and criteria should be first.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a pro at Excel but I think you can solve this with INDEX().

- http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/
- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-b61bc266-fe02-4852-aad9-77bf8ca3c036
- http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/index_function.php

Or if you go into Range.FindNext Method

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143.aspx

Hope some if this will help you.

**EDIT:** sorry. I was wrong. But learned a lot.

Comment: actually I already have done this index match thing, as you can see in my question update, but my problem is to count them and the `type1` is not always one row below the `code1`.

Comment: Sorry. I was wrong. But I learned a lot. Good look @Mpondomise. Have a nice day!